# How to use variables with double quotes into Regular Exception?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace the "3" into "5". When it is using static it's working fine but when I use it through variable `var allvar= '"3"';` it's not working fine.

Here is the [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Wsmemon/23ykfjh8/)

Comment: The question is really unclear. If you just want to replace 3 into 5, you can just use string.replace(new RegExp('3', 'g'), '5').

Comment: Indeed. Also, please don't add unnecessary tags. This question has nothing to do with [tag:jquery], [tag:jquery-ui], [tag:jquery-mobile] or [tag:javascript-objects].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string 
see the link for your help and reference

Comment: Ok dear @Amadan

Answer (score 4):

`new RegExp( /[allvar]+/g );` will construct a regular expression matching all uninterrupted sequences of one or more characters from the set `a, l, v, a, r`.

To construct a regular expression from a variable, you can do this:

```
new RegExp(allvar, 'g')
```

It would also be good to escape characters with special meaning to RegExp, unless you intend for `allvar` to contain regexp source. Unfortunately, `RegExp.escape` is [still not in the language](https://github.com/benjamingr/RegExp.escape), so one would use a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex/6969486#6969486).

```
new RegExp(escapeRegExp(allvar), 'g')
```